# C code parser to track function calls and variable accesses within a project (emacs compatibility would be nice)

Tags: c, parsing, emacs, function-calls

What I would like is a tool to be able to tell me which functions call a particular function A() (in a C project), and which functions call those functions etc so that I can have a list of functions which i know that when they are called, there is a possibility that function A() will be called.

For example we have the following functions scattered in a project:

```
 void A()
 { /*does something*/ }

 void B()
 {
   A();
   /*and more stuff*/
 }

 void C()
 {
if(unlikely_to_be_false)
    A()
/* moar stoff */
 }

 void D()
 {
/* code that does not refer to A() at all */
 }

 void E()
 {
C()
 }
```

When the awesome tool is run with parameter A, It will return somehow a the functions B C and E.

Close to this but not exactly i would like to accomplish this:
Given a variable somewhere in a project find all read/write operations(direct or indirect) to it.

For example:

```
void A()
{
    char* c; // this is our little variable

    B(c); // this is in the resulting list
}

void B(char* x)
{
    printf("%c", x); // this is definately in the list

    *x='d' // this is also in the list

    C(x); // also in the list
}

void C(void* ptr)
{
    ptr = something; // also in the list
}
```

If the above could play well with emacs i would be most delighted!

Comment: Kindly accept answers if you have got the required info

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could have a look on cscope tool (http://cscope.sourceforge.net/). It supports very large projects and a lot of different queries type :

- Find this C symbol
- Find this global definition
- Find functions called by this function
- Find functions calling this function
  ...

Comment: I just managed to get this to work, not extremely intelligent but it is a step up from grep.

Answer (score 2):

First, there is the issue of calls between different compilation units, e.g. `foo.c` defining function `foo1` calling function `bar2` defined in `bar.c` (and that `bar2` might call a `foobar` defined in `foo.c` or in another file `foofoo.c`)

Then, you might consider perhaps developing a GCC plugin or a [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/) extension to suit your needs.

You could also buy a costly static analyzer tool.

Emacs has [cedet](http://cedet.sourceforge.net/) which might interest you.

Comment: "First, there is the issue of calls between different compilation units." Could you elaborate on that a bit?

Comment: I improved my answer to explain it.

Comment: Thank you! Well I am refering to textual analysis not involving the compiler. It is my understanding that this should be cake for tools like semantic for emacs. I also find this quite useful, I am surprised that nobody has ever looked for this before.

Comment: @fakedrake: Textual analysis to determine function calls?   How will textual analysis see indirect function calls, function calls to another compilation unit, function calls in a macro, or function calls enabled/disabled by preprocessor conditionals?  If you don't mind bad answers, you can regexp for   "<identifier>(" but otherwise you need a real parser to do this decently.

Comment: @IraBaxter: I expect a search in a tree of functions: what you say does is what i do to get over this at the moment but then i have to grep every function that calls <identifier> too and then every function that calls each one of those functions etc. so I end up with the names of all the functions that when called it is possible that <idetifier> will be called later in the stack.

Comment: @fakedrake:  (read my remark again). What do you do if the text you see is " (*foo)();  "?  One needs to figure out what foo could point to, requiring points to analysis, requiring deep analysis of the code... not easily done on text.

Comment: The point to all this really is if i change the behavior of a function which other functions may be affected, so debuging the executable gets awkward as the project becomes larger and/or poorly tested.
I am not saying it is trivial, I am saying it is useful and possile.

Comment: What i do as a step up from rgrep is cscope backend for semantic ;) Thank you